# How to 'break' out of a Boolean "OR' XPath if first XPath matches?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using Webdriver in Python, I'm looking for a certain element, and if it's not found, I try find a different element that is usually present if the first is not. Problem is: it appears that the second XPath is sometimes evaluated first, and when it returns a valid value, it's not the value I need **when both elements are present**.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span | //ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/span").text
```

The first XPath query is my ideal scenario, and if it returns a valid value, I need it to break out of the `OR`, so that the second XPath is not evaluated and possibly returned. Or alternativley, force it to evaluate the first expression and only if it does not return a match does it evaluate the second. What are my options here?

**UPDATE** 
Here's what I'm *actually* trying to do: On the left hand side of a Google local search results page such as [this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=chiropractors%2Bnew%20york%2Bny&rflfq=1&tbm=lcl&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:2&oll=40.753684075373776,-73.98139879999997&ospn=0.009947864395265071,0.01613616943359375&oz=16&fll=40.75791015795404,-73.95807431040645&fspn=0.03978892801050904,0.064544677734375&fz=14&rlfi=hd:;si:3230429390063131671&rlha=0), there are 20 results:

[image]

I want to extract the review score for each (not the star rating, but the number of reviews), whether it is non-zero, or 'No reviews'. **Problem is:** in the boolean OR Xpath above, it sometimes grabs the star-rating, not the review score:

```
In [14]: for i in range(1,21):
   ....:     reviews.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span | //ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/span" % (i,i)))

In [16]: [i.text for i in reviews]
Out[16]: 
[u'5.0',
 u'4 reviews',
 u'4 reviews',
 u'4.3',
 u'2 reviews',
 u'No reviews',
 u'4.9',
 u'3 reviews',
 u'5.0',
 u'2 reviews',
 u'No reviews',
 u'4.9',
 u'4 reviews',
 u'3 reviews',
 u'No reviews',
 u'No reviews',
 u'4.9',
 u'No reviews',
 u'No reviews',
 u'4.7']
```

So what I've done is replaced it with a try/except:

```
            for result in range(1,21):
                try:
                    reviewCount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/span" % result).text
                    reviewCounts.append(int(reviewCount.split()[0].replace(',','')))
                except:
                    #reviewCount = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ol/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[%s]/div/div[3]/div/a[1]/div/div/div[2]/span" % result).text
                    reviewCounts.append(0)
            print '\t ****** Review counts for city %s : %s' % (city, reviewCounts)
```

But this is operation is **extremely** slow, often taking up to 2 minutes (really).

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code of the elements? It could help to find an alternative.

Comment: @alecxe Done, plus added more detail. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using css selectors instead? it should be faster

Answer (score 2):

The "|" operator in XPath is not a boolean OR, it is a union operator: it forms the union of two node-sets. So the result of the expression contains the results of both selections.

I don't know what `driver.find_element_by_xpath()` does, but my guess would be that it takes the first node in the node-set delivered by the XPath expression, in document order - which could come from either operand of the union expression.

Solving this in XPath 2.0 would be dead easy, but I suspect Python is only offering you XPath 1.0. If that's the case, I suspect the best solution is some conditional logic in Python. In pseudo code replace

```
find(A | B)
```

by

```
X = find(A)
if (X is empty) {
  X = find(B)
}
```

This is roughly what you are doing I think (I don't know Python), except you are doing it by forcing an exception when X is empty. In most languages, forcing an exception and catching it is vastly more expensive than using exception-free logic.

Answer (score 1):

Me again and I'll also provide the java code for you.

**Note**： here my ‘|’ works well. I try to get the star and if no stars there it will returns the reviews' count. The output on my side is in Chinese so i won't put it here(:( you might not recognize whats that.). Test is based on firefox.

```
package com.selenium.webdriver.test;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class OrCondition {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                "http://192.168.12.100:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=t1bdVbaJKcu9eO3KhLAN&fg=1#q=chiropractors&rflfq=1&tbm=lcl&tbs=lf_msr:-1,lf:1,lf_ui:1&oll=37.10749322441741,-95.47923175&ospn=0.9812998917572173,3.251953125&oz=8&fll=36.65933277945504,-94.52342120312498&fspn=1.8859928637987977,5.16357421875&fz=8&rlfi=hd:;si:&rlha=0");
        //0. Here wait for the items load
        WebElement wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
                .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {

                    @Override
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
                        return d.findElement(By.className("_gt"));

                    }
                });
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //1. the same with yesterday's question.
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath("//div[@class='_gt']"));

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            WebElement e = elements.get(i);

            WebElement aTag = e.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

            // String dataCid = aTag.getAttribute("data-cid");
            //2. Use "|" 
            WebElement starSpan = aTag
                    .findElement(By
                            .xpath(".//g-review-stars/span | .//div[span[contains(text(),'reviews')]]"));

            if (starSpan.getAttribute("aria-label") != null) {
                System.out.println(starSpan.getAttribute("aria-label"));
            } else {
                System.out.println(starSpan.getText());
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //3. it costs about 2.5 seconds
        System.out.println("Time elapsed " + (end - start));
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working java code for above problem. (As jeffC told, I hope you can convert it too python compatible.)

```
        List<WebElement> names=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@role='link']//div[@role='heading']"));
        List<WebElement> reviews=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@role='link']//span[contains(text(),'reviews') and not(@class)]"));
        int i=0;
        for(WebElement ele1:names) {
            System.out.println(ele1.getText()+"==>"+reviews.get(i).getText());
            i++
        }
```

And the output is

```
Jamie H Bassel DC PC==>2 reviews
Rockefeller Health & Medical Chiropractic==>14 reviews
Frank J. Valente, DC, PC==>3 reviews
Elite Health & Sports Chiropractic==>No reviews
Dr. Robert Shire==>4 reviews
Klein Chiropractic Associates==>No reviews
Better Health Chiropractic PC==>21 reviews
Ron Safko DC, Chiropractic==>5 reviews
Dr Siri Smith DC==>No reviews
JW Chiropractic==>10 reviews
Midtown West - Westside Chiropractic==>No reviews
Carnegie Chiropractic, P.C.==>No reviews
43rd Medical==>No reviews
Balanced Health Medical Chiropractic==>30 reviews
Specific Chiropractic==>3 reviews
John J. Belmonte D.C.,P.C.==>2 reviews
Dr. Shawn M. Turner, DC==>No reviews
Ronald Bland, DC==>No reviews
John F. Brown, DC==>No reviews
BLEU HEALTH SPORTS CHIROPRACTIC, PC==>No reviews
```